# What is the meaning of PicturePileLayerContent(...): Warning: painting PicturePile without content

Tags: android, webview

I am getting this warning when getting HTML content from server to WebView and HTML contains img src tag
Example: sequences represents the increasing order of the polarizing power of the cationic species
img src="http://www.demo.com/Images_demopractice/Chemistry/Q788.jpg"

```
11-06 01:35:44.129: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.139: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.149: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.209: D/dalvikvm(2179): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 931K, 32% free 3704K/5380K, paused 47ms, total 51ms
11-06 01:35:44.219: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.279: I/Choreographer(2179): Skipped 99 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 01:35:44.289: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.359: D/webviewglue(2179): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a364078
11-06 01:35:44.359: D/webviewglue(2179): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a38b3a0
11-06 01:35:44.359: D/webviewglue(2179): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a4f6f40
11-06 01:35:44.388: D/webviewglue(2179): nativeDestroy view: 0x2a4f6fc8
11-06 01:35:44.419: I/Choreographer(2179): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 01:35:44.448: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.448: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.448: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.508: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.518: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:44.924: I/Choreographer(2179): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-06 01:35:45.119: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.119: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.159: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.169: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.169: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.209: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.219: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.219: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.229: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.269: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.279: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.289: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.289: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.319: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.329: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.339: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.339: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.389: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.399: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.409: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
11-06 01:35:45.419: W/PicturePileLayerContent(2179): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

Comment: format your post please.

Comment: In my case, this is related to AdMob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is AdMob related, try disable it and look if that message is still appearing.